# the remote server returned an error 414 request uri too long

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am using SaveBinaryDirect method to upload file to SharePoint library. I am getting error like below
the remote server returned an error 414 request uri too long

Can anybody help me please

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call this a SharePoint problem necessarily, more like a problem that happens a lot in SharePoint... Essentially, you have around a 2,000 character limit for the URL.  In most scenarios this is fine, however in SharePoint it occasionally becomes an issue.

Users tend to create a lot of nested libraries and the name of each library becomes part of the URL - separated by '/'.  Then the file name is added at the end of the URL.  And to make matters worse, if there are any spaces or un-URL friendly characters, they are encoded and become three characters each - space becomes %20.  This all adds up.

In my experience the solution is a combination of user education and proper architecture.  Instead of creating nested libraries, store the documents in a single library and differentiate the items by assigning meta-data attributes, then create views to display items of a particular type.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also be cause by having "invalid" characters in the filename or path. See this answer for what makes a character invalid in a URI:

[Which characters make a URL invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid)